# Http POST Curl in python

Tags: python, http, post, curl, facebook-opengraph

I'm having trouble understanding how to issue an HTTP POST request using curl from inside of python.

I'm tying to post to facebook open graph. Here is the example they give which I'd like to replicate exactly in python.

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```

Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) to POST with Python or the higher level [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib

params = {}

params['access_token'] = '*****'
params['message'] = 'Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.'

params = urllib.urlencode(params)
f = urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed", params)
print f.read()
```

There is also a Facebook specific higher level library for Python that does all the POST-ing for you.

https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/

<strike>https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk</strike>

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use curl in the first place?

Python has extensive libraries for *Facebook* and included libraries for web requests, calling another program and receive output is unecessary.

That said,

First from Python Doc

> `data` may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server,
>   or `None` if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the
>   only ones that use data; **the HTTP request will be a `POST` instead of a
>   GET when the data parameter is provided**. `data` should be a buffer in
>   the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. The
>   urllib.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples
>   and returns a string in this format. urllib2 module sends HTTP/1.1
>   requests with Connection:close header included.

So,

```
import urllib2, urllib
parameters = {}
parameters['token'] = 'sdfsdb23424'
parameters['message'] = 'Hello world'
target = 'http://www.target.net/work'

parameters = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
handler = urllib2.urlopen(target, parameters)
while True:
    if handler.code < 400:
        print 'done'
        # call your job
        break
    elif handler.code >= 400:
        print 'bad request or error'
        # failed
        break
```